Need help breaking/fixing the psmouse kernel module
I have an issue with the trackpoint on my ThinkPad. After holding it in a direction for about 5 seconds, it recalibrates the center point to the position where it is being held. This means that after recalibration, if you release the trackpoint, the cursor moves on its own in the opposite direction. You then have to wait with your finger off the trackpoint until it recalibrates again to the real center. This happens all the time, and it's super frustrating to have to release the trackpoint and wait.
I'm looking to turn this feature off by breaking the driver. I've tracked down the driver in the psmouse kernel module, specifically trackpoint.h and trackpoint.c. I've tried changing the TP_DRIFT_TIME and TP_DEF_DRIFTTIME macros, but it doesn’t seem to make any difference. I've also tried setting the TP_RECALIB command to zero, thinking that if it couldn't run the recalibrate command, it wouldn't recalibrate. I confirmed that it’s using trackpoint.h and trackpoint.c because I put a print statement in the init function, which helps me keep track of my edits to the kernel module when loading. Beyond that, I’m in over my head trying to figure out the rest of the driver.
If I could make the period for recalibration much longer (20-30 seconds), I doubt I would run into so many resets. If someone could take a look at the driver code and point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.
I should also mention that the kernel module has some parameters that can be set, like resetafter and resync_time, but changing those values also doesn’t make a difference. However, the parameter for resolution does work.  The trackpoint is an Elan TPPS/2.
